# C# Get Microsoft ReportViewer to load XDocument contents

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, report

I have an Xdocument object which is populated with xml (the definition for a report -rdl). I would like to give the contents of this XDocument to the report viewer.

```
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.LoadReportDefinition();
```

LoadReportDefinition only seems to take either TextReader or FileStream arguments....but my report definition is loaded within my XDocument? How can I stream the contents of my XDocument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `StringReader` class like so:

```
using (var textReader = new StringReader(xDocument.ToString()))
{
  this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.LoadReportDefinition(textReader);
}
```

Or alternatively use a `Stream`:

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream()) 
{
  xDocument.Save(stream);
  stream.Position = 0;
  this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.LoadReportDefinition(stream);
}
```